# AFNetworking and id reponseObject NOT working and not able to recover the content

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

After few days of job I am not able to solve this issue, I really need your help because I am completely locked, I start to be crazy!!!!!!. I have a project in Objective c for iOS where I get data from my server to put in my application. I have some trouble to recover and save data from JSON.

I would like to use "id responseObject", and save and use the content in another area in my project. Each time I try to use the following method and use "id responseObject" outside of "setCompletionBlockWithSucess" the "id responseObject" is (null), how can I do ?

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"…."];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op]
```

Comment: This question is so grammatically wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't quite understand what `scope` is for variables. This project may be too advanced for you if that's the case. I urge you to read into scope + blocks to get a better understanding of what's going on.

What is happening is the `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` is actually a block of code that gets executed if the URL request is a success. This means that `responseObject` is not immediately executed! It's being passed back some time after and you get access to it within `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess`. So that's why it's nil outside of the block.

To do what you're wanting is very simple. You need to read `responseObject` within the `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` and set it to another variable that you have access to. Or you can immediately send it to another class to parse/save.

I haven't tested it, but I believe this should work with a simple JSON response. If not, use `operation.responseString` instead

```
NSString *jsonResponse;
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"…."];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id   responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    jsonResponse = responseObject;
}
```

...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer I appreciate your immediate answer. That is more clear for me, I sent the variable and parse it in another class and it works like a charm !. As you advised me I will study more in deepth this part of Objective C programming which is sope+blocks